# jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only in one calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have found this code in this page..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    }
});
});
</script>
 <style>
  .ui-datepicker-calendar {
display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="startDate">Date :</label>
    <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
</body>
</html>
```

And works if you have only one calendar at the same page, but if I have two calendars, hides the days in both, and i want that only be applied in one calendar.. Someone can tell me how can i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By using `$('.date-picker').datepicker({` you init all your calendars with the same settings, specifically date format, so you need to init them separately. E.g. if your calendars have ids "firstCalendar" and "secondCalendar", init first one as above:

```
$('#firstCalendar').datepicker( {
    dateFormat: 'MM yy'
});
```

And the second one with default dateFormat:

```
$('#secondCalendar').datepicker( {
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
   display: none;
}
```

Try this one [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXnCM/)

Comment: Why -1? 
In jsfiddle I've provided solution where you need to mark inputs where you want to pick only months with `.monthPicker` class.
So if you want to pick only month add `.monthPicker` else just don't add that class.